# prevent bash from automatically executing a command I pull from history

Tags: bash

Because I am an old-time `tcsh` user, I tend to grab my `bash` history by using the exclamation mark followed by the first word of the command I'm trying to pull up. On `tcsh` this causes it to display the command, but on `bash` it runs the command, without giving me a chance to edit it.

Is there any way to get `bash` to show me the command *without* running it?

Comment: You should read [Searching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Searching) in the manual: `Ctrl-R`, start typing the command, when it's found `Esc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:p` modifier to merely print the command:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ !!:p
echo foo
```

There are also two ways to just expand a history specifier on the current command line rather than executing it immediately.

1. The Readline command `history-expand` (bound by default to `M-^`) expands any history specifiers on the current command line in place.
2. The shell option `histverify` (`shopt -s histverify`) puts the expansion of the current command line on the next command line when you hit Enter, rather than executing it immediately.

Both of the preceding allow you to further edit the resulting command before executing it.

Comment: That's my favorite option, too. Having to hit enter a second time, when I'm already sure the expansion is what I want to execute, isn't a big deal.